# Rails scope where clause find nested array value in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
[#<User
  id: 5,
  name: "Dave",
  email: "example@gmail.com",
  info:
   {"years_old"=>"30",
    "recent_purchases"=>["car", "house", "boat"]}>]
```

Let's assume that I'm saving recent purchases to `{info: { recent_purchases: [])` in user model

I want to make a scope to get users with only `'car'` in recent purchases. I can't change database structure so I have to figure it out

I've tried this `User.where("info->>'recent_purchases' IN (?)", 'car')` but it doesn't work

This also didn't work - `User.where("info->>'recent_purchases' = ?", ["car"])`

Edit:
Thanks to @Jacob, this worked perfectly!

```
User.where("where info -> 'recent_purchases' ? :car and jsonb_array_length(info -> 'recent_purchases') = 1", car: 'car')
```

Edit2:

If you want to create a scope for a user that has a car in his recent_purchases, that's how you do it:

```
scope :where_cars_included, -> { where("info::jsonb -> 'recent_purchases' ? :purchase", purchase: 'car') }
```

For scope with ONLY cars in recent_purchases:

```
scope :only_cars, -> { where("info::jsonb -> 'recent_purchases' ? :purchase and json_array_length(info -> 'recent_purchases') = 1", purchase: 'car') }
```

There is a small guide that can help:

[How to query PostgreSQL's json fields from Rails](https://makandracards.com/makandra/37851-how-to-query-postgresql-s-json-fields-from-rails)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get users with a car in recent_purchases

```
User.where("info -> 'recent_purchases' ? :car", car: car)
```

Get users with only a car in recent_purchases

```
User.where("info -> 'recent_purchases' = to_jsonb(array[:car])", car: car)
```

an alternative to the previous example

```
User.where("info -> 'recent_purchases' ? :car and jsonb_array_length(info -> 'recent_purchases') = 1", car: car)
```

If info is json instead of jsonb then cast it to jsonb

```
info::jsonb
```

See PostgreSQL documentation for more ways to query against json/jsonb:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html